# How do i make Django accept my date formats

Tags: python-3.x, django, date, django-models

How can i make my model date field accept the 'dd/mm/yyyy' date format?

I have seen the solutions using django forms but i am not using django forms.

Please help.

Comment: You don't. The parsing is hardcoded for a model field: https://github.com/django/django/blob/bebd4cfa8f5e0d2dff2de5e50d86e849a40f4bb2/django/utils/dateparse.py#L22-L27

Comment: It does not make much sense anyway to process request data yourself. Data is validated and cleaned with a form. You do not need to *render* that form, but forms should be use to validate data.

Comment: You really should use django forms. They do so much for you.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of a way i can transform the date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format to the django accepted "yyyy/mm/dd" format?

Comment: @Chymdy: yes, use a form. Manually processing data in the view only results in a lot of boilerplate code, it makes the view inflexible, and sometimes can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Lol.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django settings.py has a date input area, the defaults are here.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

```
[
    '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', # '2006-10-25', '10/25/2006', '10/25/06'
    '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y',            # 'Oct 25 2006', 'Oct 25, 2006'
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y',            # '25 Oct 2006', '25 Oct, 2006'
    '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y',            # 'October 25 2006', 'October 25, 2006'
    '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y',            # '25 October 2006', '25 October, 2006'
]
```

However, if one needs more control, python's strptime() module does this

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '16-12-2020 08:15:27.243860'
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap datepicker as i used in my form, you can simply change the date format in the datepicker.js file or alternatively add the attribute data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd".